# Laravel - using 'where' in routes.php to query a model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am looking to flatten my routes for an ecommerce store for SEO purposes.

I would like to create the following routes:

```
Route::get('/{country}', ['uses' => 'Store\ProductController@browseCountry']);
Route::get('/{category}, ['uses' => 'Store\ProductController@browseCategory']')
```

The `country` and `category` must be dynamic.

I would like to know if something like the following is possible? and the best way of achieving.

```
// Route 1
Route::get('/{country}', ['uses' => 'Store\ProductController@browseCountry'])
    ->where('country', ProductCountry::select('slug')->get());

// Route 2
Route::get('/{category}', ['uses' => 'Store\ProductController@browseCategory'])
    ->where('category', ProductCategory::select('slug')->get());
```

example routes:

```
/great-britain should be routed via Route 1
/china         should be routed via Route 1

/widgets       should fail route 1, but be routed via Route 2 because 
               widgets are not in the product_country table but are in 
               the product_category table
```

I know that I can hardcode my routes with possible countries:

```
Route::get('/{country}', ['uses' => 'Store\ProductController@browse'])
    ->where('country', 'great-britain|china|japan|south-africa');
```

However this is clumsy and tedius. I would like to get the list of countries from the database.

Comment: surely that would be handled in your controller not in your route you'd pass country regardless into your controller but then the controler would do your if country == do xxx else do yyy etc

Comment: You can use the Route::model() to achieve that.

Comment: @Dave - How do I pass the route to the country if I wish to restrict specific countries to be available to the controller? Doing your method, my route would have to be `Route::get('country'/{country})` which I do not want.

Comment: @Anam - Could you provide an example of how to achieve that?

Comment: I have updated my question to bring some clarity on what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 3):

i will do it this way i choose the country model because there are less models+ you need to cache that:
change lists('name') to the country name column

```
Route::get('/{country}', ['uses' => 'Store\ProductController@browseCountry'])
->where('country', implode('|',ProductCountry::select('slug')->lists('name')));
```

what is does is select all countries name and return them as array like this

```
 ('usa','england','thailand')
```

and use implode with '|' as glue return this:

```
usa|england|thailand
```

so your final route is like this:

```
Route::get('/{country}', ['uses' => 'Store\ProductController@browseCountry'])
->where('country', 'usa|england|thailand');
```

Comment: This breaks my migrations because artisan loads routes.php and without the migration the query in routes.php will fail. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: @Ezra why dont change the routes to something like category/{category} ?

Comment: I wish I could but the route I need to build has to work like this. I fixed it by allowing me to pass a closure to Route:pattern and Route::where and only running this callback just before laravel calls the symfony router. Artisan doesn't actually use the route to this callback is only called if the route is really used to my problem is gone!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after reviewing your updated question, you'll want to create a method within your respective models to concatenate all available slugs with the | character, so you'd call something like:

```
Route::get('/{country}', ['uses' => 'Store\ProductController@browseCountry'])
     ->where('country', ProductCountry::getSlugs());
```

This would pretty much return 'great-britain|china|japan|south-africa' like in your example, except you wouldn't have to write it.

I would however, strongly recommend, that you give the routes something a bit more, /country/{country} or /category/{category} otherwise it's confusing, and the URI structure is often this way so that users can accurately see where they are.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a go. I understand your recommendation and do agree with it to an extent. however do you ever see online stores with the words category or country in the URL?

Comment: Category yes, country not so much. Depends on the purpose really.

Comment: country is usually stored via a session tbh on most stores I've seen

Answer (score 0):

You need route filters to achieve that.

place the following code to `filters.php` or in the `route.php` file

```
Route::filter('country', function()
{

    $country = Country::where('slug', Route::input('country'))->first();
    if(  ! $country) {
        dd("We do not support this country");
            // Redirect::route('home');
    }

});
```

and finally your route:

```
Route::get('country/{country}', array('before' => 'country', 'uses' => 'Store\ProductController@browseCountry'));
```